# How to make fading-to-black effect with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, blending

Im trying to achieve fade-to-black effect, but i dont know how to do it. I tried several things but they fail due to how opengl works

I will explain how it would work:

If i draw 1 white pixel and move it around each frame for one pixel to some direction, each frame the screen pixels will get one R/G/B value less (of range 0-255), thus after 255 frames the white pixel will be fully black. So if i move the white pixel around, i would see a gradient trail going from white to black evenly 1 color value difference compared to previous pixel color.

**Edit:** I would prefer to know non-shader way of doing this, but if its not possible then i can accept shader-way too.

**Edit2:** Since there is some confusion around here, I would like to tell that i can do this kind of effect already by drawing a black transparent quad over my whole scene. BUT, this does not work as i want it to work; there is a limit on the darkness the pixels can get, so it will always leave some of the pixels "visible" (above zero color value) because: 1*0.9 = 0.9 -> rounded to 1 again, etc. I can "fix" this by making the trail shorter, but i want to be able to adjust the trail lenght as much as possible and instead of bilinear (if thats the right word) interpolation i want linear (so it would always reduce -1 from each r,g,b value in 0-255 scale, instead of using a percent value).

**Edit3:** Still some confusion left, so lets be clear: i want to improve the effect that is done by disabling GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT from glClear(), i dont want to see the pixels on my screen FOREVER, so i want to make them darker in time, by drawing a quad over my scene that will reduce each of the pixels color value by 1 (in 0-255 scale).

**Edit4:** I'll make it simple, i want OpenGL method for this, the effect should use as little power, memory or bandwidth as possible. this effect is supposed to work without clearing the screen pixels, so if i draw a transparent quad over my scene, the previous pixels drawn will get darker etc. But as explained above few times, its not working very well. The big NO's are: 1) reading pixels from screen, modifying them one by one in a for loop and then uploading back. 2) rendering my objects X times with different darknesses to emulate the trail effect. 3) multiplying the color values is not an option since it wont make the pixels into black, they will stay on the screen forever at certain brightness (see explanation somewhere above).

Comment: Can you write a simple test program that would demonstrate the problem? It may well be how you're initializing OpenGL or something.

Comment: @Nicol, i noticed the graphical fading incorrectness was caused by  incorrect blending function, check my edits for the new problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If i draw 1 white pixel and move it around each frame for one pixel to some direction, each frame the screen pixels will get one R/G/B value less (of range 0-255), thus after 255 frames the white pixel will be fully black. So if i move the white pixel around, i would see a gradient trail going from white to black evenly 1 color value difference compared to previous pixel color.

Before I explain how to do this, I would like to say that the visual effect you're going for is a terrible visual effect and you should not use it. Subtracting a value from each of the RGB colors will produce a *different color*, not a darker version of the same color. The RGB color (255,128,0), if you subtract 1 from it 128 times, will become (128, 0, 0). The first color is brown, the second is a dark red. These are not the same.

Now, since you haven't really explained this very well, I have to make some guesses. I am assuming that there are no "objects" in what you are rendering. There is no state. You're simply drawing stuff at arbitrary locations, and you don't remember what you drew where, nor do you want to remember what was drawn where.

To do what you want, you need two off-screen buffers. I recommend using [FBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object)s and screen-sized textures for these. The basic algorithm is simple. You render the previous frame's image to the current image, using a blend mode that "subtracts 1" from the colors you write. Then you render the new stuff you want to the current image. Then you display that image. After that, you switch which image is previous and which is current, and do the process all over again.

Note: The following code will assume OpenGL 3.3 functionality.

### Initialization

So first, during initialization (after OpenGL is initialized), you must create your screen-sized textures. You also need two screen-sized depth buffers.

```
GLuint screenTextures[2];
GLuint screenDepthbuffers[2];
GLuint fbos[2]; //Put these definitions somewhere useful.

glGenTextures(2, screenTextures);
glGenRenderbuffers(2, screenDepthbuffers);
glGenFramebuffers(2, fbos);
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, screenTextures[i]);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, screenDepthBuffers[i]);
  glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[i]);
  glFramebufferTexture(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, screenTextures[i], 0);
  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, screenDepthBuffers[i]);
  if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    //Error out here.
  }
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

### Drawing Previous Frame

The next step will be drawing the previous frame's image to the current image.

To do this, we need to have the concept of a previous and current FBO. This is done by having two variables: `currIndex` and `prevIndex`. These values are indices into our GLuint arrays for textures, renderbuffers, and FBOs. They should be initialized (during initialization, not for each frame) as follows:

```
currIndex = 0;
prevIndex = 1;
```

In your drawing routine, the first step is to draw the previous frame, subtracting one (again, I strongly suggest using a real blend here).

This won't be full code; there will be pseudo-code that I expect you to fill in.

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbos[currIndex]);
glClearColor(...);
glClearDepth(...);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, screenTextures[prevIndex]);
glUseProgram(BlenderProgramObject); //The shader will be talked about later.

RenderFullscreenQuadWithTexture();

glUseProgram(0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

The `RenderFullscreenQuadWithTexture` function does exactly what it says: renders a quad the size of the screen, using the currently bound texture. The program object `BlenderProgramObject` is a GLSL shader that does our blend operation. It fetches from the texture and does the blend. Again, I'm assuming you know how to set up a shader and so forth.

The fragment shader would have a main function that looks something like this:

```
shaderOutput = texture(prevImage, texCoord) - (1.0/255.0);
```

Again, I strongly advise this:

```
shaderOutput = texture(prevImage, texCoord) * (0.05);
```

If you don't know how to use shaders, then you should learn. But if you don't want to, then you can get the same effect using a [glTexEnv](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml) function. And if you don't know what those are, I suggest [learning shaders](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/); it's so much easier in the long run.

### Draw Stuff As Normal

Now, you just render everything you would as normal. Just don't unbind the FBO; we still want to render to it.

### Display the Rendered Image on Screen

Normally, you would use a swapbuffer call to display the results of your rendering. But since we rendered to an FBO, we can't do that. Instead, we have to do something different. We must blit our image to the backbuffer and then swap buffers.

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbos[currIndex]);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 0, SCREEN_WDITH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
//Do OpenGL swap buffers as normal
```

### Switch Images

Now we need to do one more thing: switch the images that we're using. The previous image becomes current and vice versa:

```
std::swap(currIndex, prevIndex);
```

And you're done.

Comment: You are just showing an implementation of my concept; makes you look like a freeloader. What is the point of doing a complete implementation of the task and not leaving the OP something to do so that he would learn something? Btw, I have the suspicion the OP wants to render a (volumetric) particle effect, maybe smoke. If so, I doubt that his plan of writing millions of moving pixels per frame will work anyway.

Comment: @Nicol, multiplying the color will make the bug i talked about; thats why i cant multiply, or i will see previous frame pixels FOREVER on the screen at certain brightness. also, do i need FBO if i disabled GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT from glClear() ? i dont care how "quality effect" it will be, i only care about speed.

Comment: @karx11erx, im not rendering smoke, just some particles flying around, and leaving nice trail, while using as little power and memory in GPU as possible. by million i might have been exaggarated a bit ;)

Comment: @Rookie: Multiplying will not make the color be there "FOREVER". A value of 1.0, when continuously multiplied by 0.95, will eventually become zero. And it will do so without changing the actual color. I suppose you could get away without clearing the color buffer, since you're just going to write a full-screen quad. And I have no idea why you wouldn't care about the quality of the effect.

Comment: If you want the a pixel from the pixel trail to disappear 255 frames after it has first been rendered, you need to decrease each color channel of the pixel by <initial channel value> / 255.0, each frame. That will make the channels all reach zero simultaneously - but will require more data (you need to memorize the proper channel decrements for each pixel).

Comment: @nicol, where in your example code do you tell the opengl to allocate floats for the pixel values in the FBO? because that would be the only way to make the multiplication actually work. Isnt there a way to do this without FBO? i really dont care about the color quality, just the speed. optimal solution would be to use a shader that modifies the current buffer pixels 1 value lower and does nothing else, no extra memory allocated whatsoever. is that possible anyhow?

Comment: @Rookie: You don't need float pixels; 8-bit normalized integers is plenty for your needs. OpenGL does the conversion internally, just as it does with any 8-bit normalized integer textures and framebuffers. And no, there is no way to do it without FBOs or some other form of off-screen rendering. OpenGL makes _no_ guarantees about the state of the framebuffer after doing a buffer swap.

Comment: if i dont need to change my pixel format, how will this actually solve the problem of pixels which never fade to perfect black color? (i mean if you use multiplication, there shouldnt be a problem with substraction)

Comment: @Rookie: If you have the number 1/255, and you multiply it by 0.1, it will become 0.1/255. When that is converted to an unsigned normalized integer upon being written to the framebuffer, it will round down, thus giving you 0.

Comment: how do you know it will round down, when my current implementation rounds them closest integer? (or up, i dont know which, but definitely not down since then this bug wouldnt appear!) - is it FBO feature to round it down or what?

Comment: @Rookie: Let's assume it rounds up. (2/255 * 0.1) * 255 ~= 0.2. Which would round up to 1. So you would have a value stuck on 1/255. Which is _visually indistinguishable_ from 0. And if it really, _really_ bothers you, then you can do the rounding in the shader or simply clamp a sufficiently small value to 0. More than likely, your current implementation was doing something wrong.

Comment: i think your calculations are wrong, if i want a trail of 255 pixels, i would have to use calculation such as: color*(1-(1/255)), which will get stuck on a color value 254, whereas 2/255 gets stuck to 127 etc. so the trail length = value where it gets stuck actually.

Comment: @Rookie: Why would you want a trail of _exactly_ 255 pixels? Do you think your users are going to be counting each pixel to see how long the trail is? What happens if the original pixel wasn't white? And as I pointed out, _you can do the rounding in the shader._ The problem with this discussion is that you haven't explained what _effect_ you're trying to achieve. Also, this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @Rookie let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2829/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-rookie)

Answer (score 6):

You may want to render a black rectangle with alpha going from 1.0 to 0.0 using glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_SRC_ALPHA).

Edit in response to your comment (reply doesn't fit in a comment):

You cannot fade single pixels depending on their age with a simple fade-to-black operation. Usually a render target does not "remember" what has drawn to it in previous frames. I could think of a way to do this by alternatingly rendering to one of a pair of FBOs and using their alpha channel for it, but you needed a shader there. So what you would do is first render the FBO containing the pixels at their previous positions, decreasing their alpha value by one, dropping them when alpha == 0, otherwise darkening them whenever their alpha decreases, then render the pixels at their current positions with alpha == 255.

If you only have moving pixels:

```
render FBO 2 to FBO 1, darkening each pixel in it by a scale (skip during first pass)
render moving pixels to FBO 1
render FBO 1 to FBO 2 (FBO 2 is the "age" buffer)
render FBO 2 to screen
```

If you want to modify some scene (i.e. have a scene and moving pixels in it):

```
set glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ZERO)
render FBO 2 to FBO 1, reducing each alpha > 0.0 in it by a scale (skip during first pass)
render moving pixels to FBO 1
render FBO 1 to FBO 2 (FBO 2 is the "age" buffer)
render the scene to screen
set glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_SRC_ALPHA)
render FBO 2 to screen
```

Actually the scale should be (float)  / 255.0 / 255.0 to make the components equally fade away (and not one that started at a lower value become zero before the others do).

If you only have a few moving pixels, you could re-render the pixel at all previous positions up to 255 "ticks" back.

Since you need to re-render each of the pixels anyway, just render each one with the proper color gradient: Darker, the older the pixel is. If you have a real lot of pixels, the dual FBO approach 
might work.

I am writing ticks, and not frames, because frames can take a varying amount of time depending on renderer and hardware, but you probably want to have the pixel trail fade away within a constant time. That means you need to dim each pixel only after so-and-so many milliseconds, keeping their color for the frames in between.

Comment: that will work only if i dont want to render anything on top of the fade effect... im trying to make trails visible from every rendered pixel, if the pixel moves, it will create a trail that fades to black. and there is always one pixel fully visible. every frame one value of range 0-255 will be removed from the RGB colors, thus making it darker each frame, just one value, so the next frame it will be 2 values darker etc, eventually 255 frames later its fully black.

Comment: 1) would this FBO solution need me to upload screen_x*screen_y amounts of pixel data? that is not an option for me. 2) re-rendering pixels isnt an option either (im gonna have MILLION of them). 3) if i age my pixels to get darker in time, then i wouldnt be able to see them after some time at all, and that is not what the effect is supposed to do. 4) i dont care about timings, i render everything identically no matter what FPS you have.

Comment: i added more details to my question. i dont think i need FBO if i need to use shader anyways: isnt it possible to reduce color values by just 1 with a simple shader like `color -= 1.0f/255.0f;` ? im not that experienced with shaders nor FBO so i might be wrong. BUT, i would prefer non-shader solution if its possible.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you really want. You want moving pixels to leave a darkening trail behind them, right? If so, check the modifications I have made to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One non-shader way of doing this, especially if the fade to black is the only thing that is going on the screen is to grab the contents of the screen via `readpixels` iirc, pop those into a texture, and put a rectangle up onto the screen with that texture, then you can modulate the color of the rectangle to towards black to do the efect that you want to accomplish.

Comment: Rendering to FBOs like I have described above would probably be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

It is the drivers, Windows itself does not support OpenGL or only a low Version, I think 1.5. All newer versions come with drivers from ATI or NVIDIA, Intel etc.
Are you using different cards?
What version of OpenGL are you effectivly using?

Comment: i was using same card on XP and W7, but i think the drivers are different (not sure...), my opengl version is 3.2.9655. but still, im hoping i could solve the problem without telling people to update drivers or anything, unless this is VERY rare case which only happens on one person out of million. Check out my edits, i added image to my post.

Comment: Well, do you program OpenGL3? Having the maximum Version of 3.2 does not mean that you use it :). Using OpenGL3 means not using any deprecated functions from prev. Versions.

Comment: @scorcher24: "Using OpenGL3 means not using any deprecated functions from prev. Versions." No it doesn't. If you create a compatibility context (which is the default when not using wglCreateContextAttribs), then you don't lose any functionality. And you can still use up to 4.1 (the latest version) with compatibility. Things are different on MacOSX Lion, but we're talking Windows here.

Comment: @Nicol Are we talking about forward compability? Thats something different. But just having a context which reports 3.x is not using 3.x if you, for example, still use deprecated functions. Using 3.x means sticking to the standard for 3: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/

Comment: @scorcher24: I'm talking about [core vs. compatibility](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts). Neither is more "using 3.x" than the other. Is [this OpenGL 3.3 specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec33.core.20100311.pdf) any more 3.3 than [this OpenGL 3.3 specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec33.compatibility.20100311.pdf)? (both of those are PDF links.) They both are titled "OpenGL Graphics System: A Specification." The difference is that one is for the Core profile and the other is for the Compatibility profile.

Comment: I tested some more and edited my question completely, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's situations like this that make it so I cannot use pure OpenGL.  I am not sure if your project has room for it (which it may not if you're using another windowing API), or if the added complexity would be worth it, but adding a 2D library like SDL which works with OpenGL would allow you to directly work with the display surface's pixels in a reasonable fashion, as well as just pixels in general, which OpenGL generally doesn't make easy.

Then all you would need to do is run through the display surface's pixels before OpenGL renders it's geometry, and subtract 1 from each RGB component.

That's the easiest solution I can see anyway, if using additional libraries with OpenGL is an option.

Comment: this is not an option since it would limit me to 800x600 resolution (if i want 60fps) and basically limit me from using any other streams of data at all since it would hang my bandwidth to the gfx card totally.